# Q: Player(class) java

Tags: java, eclipse

Have to code a player class in java eclipse following these requirements

a) The Player class should have a default constructor and two custom constructors - one
that accepts a Name object, and another that accepts both a Name and PairOfDice object.

b) There should be get and set methods for its Name and a get method for PairOfDice. It
should have a method called rollDice and getDiceScore that both simply delegate to the
PairOfDice class, which already has this functionality. You should also have an
appropriate toString() method.

c) Add a further void method setFullPlayerName(String) that accepts a single String
argument (e.g. “Joe Bloggs”) and then uses this to set the first and family name
individually by extracting the relevant information and then calling the respective setter
methods of the Name class.

So far I have this

---

```java
public class Player {

    //Fields of  the app
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Die red;
    private Die blue;

    //PlayerName and dice pair Default Constructor
    public Player() {
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
        red = new Die();
        blue = new Die();
    }

    public Player(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Player(String firstName, String lastName,Die red,Die blue) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.red = red;
        this.blue = blue;
    }

    // Methods
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setlastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getlastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PairOfDice:[red=" + red + ", blue=" + blue + "]";
    }


    public void rollDice() {
        red.roll();
        blue.roll();
    }

    public int getDiceScore() {
        return red.getScore() + blue.getScore();
    }

    public Die getRed() {
        return red;
    }

    public Die getBlue() {
        return blue;
    }

    public String setFullName() {
        if (firstName.equals("") && lastName.equals("")) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return firstName + " " + lastName;
        }
    }
}
```

Is my code correct? if not what changes do i have to make to correct it

Comment: Requests for reviewing existing code belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

- Dice not Die: `private Die red;`
- It's better to name your variable using a noun: `private Dice redDice;`
- Should have a `space` after a `comma`: `, Dice redDice, Dice blueDice`
- `setFullName` should accept 1 string and call `setFirstName` and `setLastName` to set the name

Example of implementation:

```
 void setFullName(String fullName) {
      /// split full name into lastName and firstName
      setFirstName(firstName); 
      setLastName(lastName);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's get this straight: This portion of the code:

```
public String setFullName() {
    if (firstName.equals("") && lastName.equals("")) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

it's misleading due to the fact that the method name it's saying that it's setting the name, BUT you're returning the name instead

So change it to this:

```
public void setFullPlayerName(String name) {
    String[] splitted = name.split(" ");
    firstname = splitted[0];
    lastname = splitted[1]
}
```

And now it's unnecessary to add the method **setFullPlayerName**

BUT I see that you may need a method to return a full name, so:

```
public String getFullPlayerName() {
    return firstname + " " + lastname;
}
```

Hopefully that'll resolve your issue :D

Comment: No, you can't say his code is correct.  It isn't.  And the code you provided will have to be modified once the other issues are corrected, although it will probably be helpful as a base.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine, but I think you forgot to define the roll() function. Besides that, everything else seems fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues with this code:

> a) The Player class should have a default constructor and two custom constructors - one that accepts a Name object, and another that accepts both a Name and PairOfDice object.
>
> b) There should be get and set methods for its Name and a get method for PairOfDice. It should have a method called rollDice and getDiceScore that both simply delegate to the PairOfDice class, which already has this functionality. You should also have an appropriate toString() method.

If it's telling you that you need a `Name` object and a `PairOfDice` object, you can't just put in two `String`s and two `Die`s and call that the same thing.  You need to actually use the `Name` and `PairOfDice` classes.

> c) Add a further void method setFullPlayerName(String) that accepts a single String argument (e.g. “Joe Bloggs”) and then uses this to set the first and family name individually by extracting the relevant information and then calling the respective setter methods of the Name class

Instead of `setFullPlayerName`, you made a method called `setFullName` that does not do what it's supposed to do.   It's supposed to accept a `String` and return `void`, and instead it accepts no parameters and returns a `String`.  It looks like a getter instead of a setter.